# Large objects in the universe sized by gravitational and electrical constants

Tags: forces, gravity, electricity, earth, observable-universe

In a famous [talk (from 14:30 to 15:00)](https://youtu.be/F2Fxt_yCrcc?t=870) Nima Arkani-Hamed tells us that what "fixes the size of the earth" is the equilibrium between the gravitational pressure against the atomic pressure of the atoms in it. He sais

> The radius of the Earth divided the radius of the atom is precisely
>   the square root of the ratio of the electric force to the
>   gravitational force between a pair of protons

Thus, if i calculate

$$
F_q/F_g=\frac{r^2}{Gm_p^2}\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon r^2}\sim1,2\cdot10^{36}
$$
I can easily find
$$
R_\oplus^2\approx F_q/F_g\cdot\langle r_{atom}\rangle^2
$$

My problem is that in order to obtain $R_\oplus^2\approx4\cdot10^{13}$ m
i must have $\langle r_{atom}\rangle^2\sim3,3\cdot10^{-23}$ m which leads to  $\langle r_{atom}\rangle\approx6\cdot10^{-10}$ m. Now to me 600 pm are nowhere near what i was expecting (something between tens and a hundred of pm)... am i confused on that or is there something i am missing?

Comment: Do all atoms have the same radius?

Comment: of course not but i was expecting something avarage and as far as i remember no one up to uranium has more than 300 pm.

Comment: Just ignore the word “precisely”. Arkani-Hamed didn’t mean it literally. You’re getting a number in the right ballpark.

Comment: If you try this with the radius of Mars, Venus or any other planet it demonstrates that equating these two ratios is ridiculous.  And you can tweak the $r$ between two protons and the $\langle r_{atom} \rangle$ more or less arbitrarily to get any result you want.  Equilibrium of forces - yes, the rest just silliness.

Comment: Exactly! i actually found a radius jupiter-like at my first guess, but i could easly reach some dwarf star radius just fooling around. I think what he intended was just to justify the macroscopic "elementary" objects tout court with no intention to be accurate, just within few orders of magnitude...

Comment: the most probable radius of the hydrogen atom is 529 x10^-13meters http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydr.html

Comment: @anna v i know but... several other sites give me different numbers: http://periodictable.com/Properties/A/AtomicRadius.v.html (53 pm), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius (25 pm empirical, 53 calculated), etc. It is clear to me that it strongly depends on how you define it...